# Analog Clock using Python Turtle library

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I tried everything to make a complete analog clock, which is attached to this question. It took me to reach this code after continuously trying for 6 hours.

[image: want to design this Analog Clock]

Here is the code:

```
import turtle
import time
import math

# Create a Turtle screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.tracer(0)

# Create a Turtle object
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(5)  # Set the drawing speed

# Function to draw a clock face with hands
def draw_clock_face():
    # Draw the clock outline
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, -150)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.circle(150)

    # Initialize the starting angle for number 12 at 90 degrees
    angle = math.radians(90)

    # Draw the clock numbers and balls
    for i in range(1, 13):
        x = 135 * math.cos(angle)  # Calculate x-coordinate
        y = -135 * math.sin(angle)  # Calculate y-coordinate

        pen.penup()
        pen.goto(x, y - 10)  # Adjust the position to center the numbers
        pen.pendown()
        pen.write(str(i), align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))

        if i in [12, 3, 6, 9]:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(x, y - 30)  # Adjust the position for the red balls
            pen.pendown()
            pen.color("red")
            pen.begin_fill()
            pen.circle(5)
            pen.end_fill()
        else:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(x, y - 30)  # Adjust the position for blue circles
            pen.pendown()
            pen.color("blue")
            pen.begin_fill()
            pen.circle(5)
            pen.end_fill()

        pen.color("black")  # Reset color to black for numbers

        # Increment the angle by 30 degrees for the next number
        angle -= math.radians(30)

# Function to draw clock hands
def draw_clock_hands():
    current_time = time.localtime()
    
    # Calculate angles for the hands
    second_angle = math.radians(90 - current_time.tm_sec * 6)
    minute_angle = math.radians(90 - current_time.tm_min * 6 - current_time.tm_sec * 0.1)
    hour_angle = math.radians(90 - (current_time.tm_hour % 12) * 30 - current_time.tm_min * 0.5)

    # Draw the second hand (black)
    second_x = 70 * math.cos(second_angle)
    second_y = 70 * math.sin(second_angle)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.color("black")
    pen.setheading(90 - current_time.tm_sec * 6)
    pen.pensize(2)
    pen.forward(second_x)
    pen.pensize(1)

    # Draw the minute hand (red)
    minute_x = 60 * math.cos(minute_angle)
    minute_y = 60 * math.sin(minute_angle)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.color("red")
    pen.setheading(90 - current_time.tm_min * 6 - current_time.tm_sec * 0.1)
    pen.pensize(3)
    pen.forward(minute_x)
    pen.pensize(1)

    # Draw the hour hand (green)
    hour_x = 40 * math.cos(hour_angle)
    hour_y = 40 * math.sin(hour_angle)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.color("green")
    pen.setheading(90 - (current_time.tm_hour % 12) * 30 - current_time.tm_min * 0.5)
    pen.pensize(5)
    pen.forward(hour_x)
    pen.pensize(1)

# Function to update the clock continuously
def update_clock():
    while True:
        pen.clear()  # Clear the previous clock hands and numbers
        draw_clock_face()  # Draw the clock face with numbers and balls
        draw_clock_hands()  # Draw the clock hands based on the current time
        screen.update()  # Update the screen
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before updating the clock again

# Main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    draw_clock_face()  # Call the function to draw the clock face
    draw_clock_hands()  # Call the function to draw the clock hands

    # Close the window when clicked
    screen.exitonclick()
```

Output of provided code:
[image: Output of this code]

I took help from different sources, likewise YouTube, ChatGPT, and Turtle documentation, but couldn't reach a solution.

Comment: There are so many differences between desired and current outputs, which one you'd like to fix first? F.ex. you start your clock (I've no idea why) with "1" at (sin(pi/2), - cos(pi/2)), while 1 is at (sin(pi/6), cos(pi/6)), etc

Comment: Could you please modify the code as per desired outcome?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please choose one problem and narrow down focus specifically that. All of your problems are distinct and can be solved in small bits, one by one, until the whole app works. For example, strip out all of the irrelevant code and focus on the hour location issue to get 12 at the top. That's focused enough to be on topic. "Fix all of my problems" is a bit too broad for the site. The code so far just looks like largely ChatGPT output that didn't work, so it's important to explain what you understand and where you're coming from as a baseline, honing in on a narrow topic/question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution. The only thing I didn't do was make the clock hands little triangles like the example, they are just lines.

I made the following changes:

1. Switch Turtle to "logo" mode so "up" is 0 degrees, and then it goes clockwise.  I had to adjust the starting position for drawing the circle based on that.
2. Removed usage of the math.radians().  Just use turtle.setheading() for everything
3. Changed the loop for drawing the face back to a range(12). Instead of calculating x and y positions, just go back to home, set the angle, and move the turtle to the right spot to put the dot.
4. Instead of drawing 12 circles for the numbers, use turtle.dot(size).
5. Split pen into two separate turtles: one for the face, and another for the hands.  Then only the hands need to be cleared to update the clock.  Also, I just included the clear call at the start of each draw function.
6. Add constants for the hand lengths for easy adjustment.  Previously you were using your hour_x/minute_x values calculated from math.radians for the hand length, which was probably leading to some confusion.

Probably some other small changes I'm not thinking of.  I did delete a lot of unnecessary code.

[image: Output at 5:58pm]

```
import turtle
import time



# Switch to Logo mode - Up = 0 degrees, then go clockwise
turtle.mode("logo")

# Clock Hand Lengths
SECOND_HAND = 110
MINUTE_HAND = 80
HOUR_HAND = 60

# Create a Turtle screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.tracer(0)

# Create a Turtle object
face = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
face.speed(5)  # Set the drawing speed
hands = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)

# Function to draw a clock face with hands
def draw_clock_face():
    # Draw the clock outline
    face.clear()
    face.penup()
    face.goto(150, 0) # Adjust position due to switch to Logo mode
    face.setheading(0)
    face.pendown()
    face.circle(150)

    # Initialize the starting angle for number 12 at 90 degrees
    

    # Draw the clock numbers and balls
    for i in range(12):
        hour = 12 if i == 0 else i
        face.penup()
        face.goto(0,0)
        face.setheading(i*30) # angle in degrees
        face.forward(125)
        face.pendown()
        face.dot(15, "red" if hour in [3, 6, 9, 12] else "blue")
        face.setheading(180)
        face.penup()
        face.forward(25)
        face.color("black")  # Reset color to black for numbers
        face.write(str(hour), align="center", font=("Arial", 10, "normal"),)

    
# Function to draw clock hands
def draw_clock_hands():

    current_time = time.localtime()
    # Clear previous hands
    hands.clear()

    # Calculate angles for the hands
    second_angle = current_time.tm_sec * 6
    minute_angle = current_time.tm_min * 6 - current_time.tm_sec * 0.1
    hour_angle = (current_time.tm_hour % 12) * 30 + current_time.tm_min * 0.5
    #print(f"{hour_angle=}  {minute_angle=}   {second_angle=}")

    # Draw the second hand (black)
    hands.penup()
    hands.goto(0, 0)
    hands.pendown()
    hands.color("black")
    hands.setheading(second_angle)
    hands.pensize(1)
    hands.forward(SECOND_HAND)

    # Draw the minute hand (red)
    hands.penup()
    hands.goto(0, 0)
    hands.pendown()
    hands.color("red")
    hands.setheading(minute_angle)
    hands.pensize(3)
    hands.forward(MINUTE_HAND)


    # Draw the hour hand (green)
    hands.penup()
    hands.goto(0, 0)
    hands.pendown()
    hands.color("green")
    hands.setheading(hour_angle)
    hands.pensize(5)
    hands.forward(HOUR_HAND)

# Function to update the clock continuously
def update_clock():
    draw_clock_face()
    while True:
        draw_clock_hands()  # Draw the clock hands based on the current time
        screen.update()  # Update the screen
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before updating the clock again

# Main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
      # Call the function to draw the clock face
    update_clock()  # Call the function to draw the clock hands
    # Close the window when clicked
    screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` may be longer than a second so you'll skip some ticks with this code. It's not a precise sleep, just a best effort, minimum wait time. Something like `time.sleep(0.1)` will avoid this. If `tracer` is off, `face.speed(5)` does nothing, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @ggorlen I agree with you the sleep increment should be smaller and the speed option does nothing visible, but I just didn't bother changing those lines while I was fixing everything else.  If any other comments come up I'll go back and edit those changes in, or you can feel free to make those edits yourself.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Answer is accepted. Thank you